# Show that $H_{DR}^2(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q)=0$ without using Mayer-Vietoris Sequence

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, differential-forms

I'm reading Bott & Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* and its Exercise 1.7 asks me to compute $H_{DR}^*(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I've figured out how to compute this for degree $0$ and $1$, but get stucked on showing that $H_{DR}^2(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q)=0$. I know how to show this using Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but this exercise is put just before the section of Mayer-Vietoris sequence, so I really wonder a solution without the use of that.

I attempted to show that every $2$-form $f(x,y)dxdy$ is exact using the integration on path to find $\alpha dx+\beta dy$ such that $d(\alpha dx+\beta dy)=fdxdy$, but it seems that with two holes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ there is not a legal choice of pathes that may work.

To find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is exactly to solve the differential equation $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}= -\frac{f}{2} $ and $\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}=\frac{f}{2}$. Is there any result for this in PDE?

Thanks in advance for any hint, solution or reference that contains a solution.

Comment: I've never noticed this exercise before. It seems very strange. They have quoted the Poincaré lemma for $H^*_{\text{DR}}(\Bbb R^n)$, but you have no tools. Even odder, have you worked out $H^*_{\text{DR}}(\Bbb R^2 - P)$ first?

Comment: @TedShifrin The method of integration along pathes works well in finding $H_{DR}^2(\mathbb{R}^2) $ but with a hole I cannot find a legal choice of pathes, so no I haven’t.

Comment: Well, for $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ you can use polar coordinates and you should be able to get it to work out fine.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm afraid that that's not true. With the origin digged out, the integration along the line from the origin to a point needs not be finite.

Comment: You need $\eta$ with $d\eta = f(r,\theta)/,dr\wedge d\theta$. Not that difficult.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, you mean putting $\eta(r,\theta)=\int_1^r f(t,\theta)dt$, right? But how can we generalize this method to $\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q$...

Answer (score 1):

I try to do this exercise and also find that the most troublesome part is proving directly that $H^2_{DR}(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q)=0$. Here is my attempt to prove:
$$
H_{D R}^2\left(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q\right)=0
$$
First, consider the case where there is only one puncture, we try to show that $H^2_{DR}(\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\})=0$. For a $C^{\infty}$ function $f(x, y)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$, the target is constructing a 1-form $\omega \in \Omega^1\left(\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}\right)$ such that $d \omega=f(x, y) d x d y$. It is routine to verify that definition of the $d$ operator doesn't depend on coordinate transformation, so we consider $f(r, \theta)$ in polar coordinates.

Define $\omega=(\int_1^r f(s, \theta) d s) d \theta$, which is just integration along the radial line from the origin. $\omega$ is then a $C^{\infty} 1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}, d \omega=f(r, \theta) d r d \theta$, as required.

[image]

We now come to the case where there are two punctures $P=(-2,0)$ and $Q=(2,0)$, we divide the construction into three steps.

Step 1: For any point $T\in \mathbb{R}^2$, If $f(r,\theta)$ is a smooth function on the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2-T$, after slightly modifying the proof above, it is guaranteed that $\exists\ \omega\in \Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2-T),d\omega=f(r,\theta)drd\theta$.

Step 2: Construct $\omega_1 \in \Omega^1\left(\mathbb{R}^2-P\right), d \omega_1=f_1(r, \theta) d r d \theta$ such that $f_1=f $ near $P$. This can be achieved if we first multiply $f(r, \theta)$ by a truncation function $\mu(x,y),$ $$\mu(x,y)=1, if\ (x+2)^2+y^2\leq 1; \mu(x,y)=0, if\ (x+2)^2+y^2\geq 4.$$ Let $g=f\cdot \mu$, then $g$ is smooth over $\mathbb{R}^2-P$ and step 1 guarantees the existence of $\omega_1, d\omega_1=g(r,\theta)drd\theta,$  as desired.

Step 3: Now $f(r,\theta)drd\theta-d\omega_1$ is supported away from $P$, we can treat it as a function on $\mathbb{R}^2-Q,$ then we can construct $\omega_2$, by step 1, $d w_2=f(r,\theta)drd\theta-d\omega_1$.

So the 2-forms in $\Omega^2(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q)$ are all exact and $H^2_{DR}(\mathbb{R}^2-P-Q)=0,$ as desired.